Power Automate Vales from Power BI to Sharepointl list
I know how to export data from PowerBI with button to sharepoint.
But this need to be automated so i need
PowerAutomate to be in charge.
I Know how to get data from
Optimize - preformense analys to DAX and then use that is Power Automate Modeul (Power BI)
But my problem is to get the values from that to sharepoint list.
If i have X rows how to i get them inside the sharepoint list. I dont get it.

Differ from the Power BI button click you get options (Entety) Look at image under.

